# error ora-12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified access 2010

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, odbc, 64-bit, oracle-client

I'm trying to connect to Oracle database through Access 2010 using Microsoft ODBC and linking the database tables, unfortunately Access shows that cannot connect to database:

Things that i done:

- Check connection through tnsping and it works.
- Check connection through odbcad32 using system DNS, it works OK. the odbcad32 is located in sysWOW64 folder, i'm using windows 7 64bit.
- Run Access 2010 as administrator.
- Create an odbc user connection inside Access but doesn't works
- Give user permissions to files sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora located in
  C:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\
- The access 2010 version in 32bit.
- The Oracle client is in 32 bit.

But at momment to select the database Access shows the 
Error ora-12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last thing that i tried it was copy the ms Access Folder located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14` **to the folder** `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Office14`,note the diference in **Program Files (x86)** to **Program Files**, and opening access from the folder ubicated in **program files**, and successfully the application recognizes the odbc driver and connection.